# Passing JSON array to PHP script using jQuery but not AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a JavaScript array which contains JSON pairs of values of the form:

```
var myArray = [{attribute: "attributeID1", option: "optionID1"},
{attribute: "attributeID2", option: "optionID2"}];
```

I have a PHP script which wants to take that data in array form and search my database with it.  I am not looking to remain on the page while this search is happening so I don't want to use AJAX - I just want to pass this data to the PHP script which will then render the new page.

What is the easiest way for me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put it in a hidden `input` element. Then submit the form that the input element is in.

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to grab a copy of json2.js so that you can convert your object into a JSON string.

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

You can then stringify your object and place it in a hidden input field in the form.

```
document.getElementById('search').value = JSON.stringify(your_object);
```

Now that will be sent over the to PHP script where you can decode it using the built in function json_decode()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$object = json_decode($_POST['search']);
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply! I've downloaded json2.js now and included that line of code you provided.  How do I include it in a hidden input field though?

Comment: `document.getElementById('hiddenId').value = JSON.stringify(yourObject);`, after the form is submitted, the json data is passed to the server